# How to change Console.app log queries' time format

Tags: logs, console, macos

I'd like to change the time format from 12 to 24 hours in the log queries.

The logs themselves are already in 24-hour, but the queries show in 12-hour format.

I checked `asl.conf`'s `man` page but I couldn't find an option, nor did perusing the actual file at `/private/etc/asl.conf`.

I also checked the default All Messages query file and a custom one, to no avail, at `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/Resources/ASLQueries/All Messages.aslquery`.

Make sure you select `View`>`Show Milliseconds` to reproduce it, which seems to override the setting `Medium` in `System Preferences`>`Language & Text`>`Region`>`Times`>`Customize…`.

I use `Console.app` v10.8 on Mountain Lion.

Comment: Have you an example query - all of my entries are in 24hr format. ALso what are your date and time settings in Preferences

Comment: If you can live with working on the command line, have a log at `man syslog`. You can conveniently search for messages, and format them how you like. Using e.g. `syslog -F '$((Time)(sec)) $Host $(Sender)[$(PID)] <$((Level)(str))>: $Message'` will print the time in seconds (epoch).

Comment: What's your 24hour clock setting in system preferences -> language & region?

Comment: ntp server is irrelevant here

Comment: @Mark, check `View`>`Show Milliseconds` to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

For El Capitan - macOS 10.11.6

Go to System Preferences->Language and Region and choose the Time Format.

Changing it to non 24hr seemed to give a quick response in Console but changing back seemed to need a restart of Console.app

Comment: As I said above, `View`>`Show Milliseconds` seems to override those settings.

Comment: Not for me    ..... and you have not mentioned what state the toggle I mentioned is you have mentioned something else

Comment: I use `Console.app` v10.8. And in System Preferences the pane is `Language & Text`, there's no `Time Format` toggle.

Comment: That needs to go in the question I am on 10.11.6

Comment: Could you post the key that's written to whatever the plist for System Preferences in El Capitan is called and saved? In 10.8 is `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist`.